# Need to find turn around time

Tags: c#

I'm calculating TAT. I have 3 params like `Current Date`, `TAT period` and `List of Holidays(Date).`

```
    static List<DateTime> Holidates = new List<DateTime>();
    static DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Now;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Holidates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(20));
        Holidates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(10));
        Holidates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(3));

        TatDueDateCalculator(DateTime.Now, 10, Holidates);
    }

    private static DateTime TatDueDateCalculator(DateTime AssignDate, int TatPeriod, List<DateTime> Holidays)
    {
        DateTime dueDate = AssignDate.AddDays(TatPeriod);

        int holiDayCount = Holidays.FindAll(x => x >= AssignDate && x <= AssignDate.AddDays(30)).Where(y => dueDate >= AssignDate && dueDate <= y).Count();

        if (holiDayCount > 0)
            dueDate = dueDate.AddDays(holiDayCount);

        return dueDate;
    }
```

`TatDueDateCalculator()` need to return `dueDate`.

Followings are the cases:

1. Continuous `Holidays`
2. `List<DateTime>Holiday` contains only one matching `dueDate`, but having greater values in the List.

For eg.

`DueDate` is `"2019-05-13"`, Holiday List contains following dates.
`"2019-05-10"`,`"2019-05-13"`,`"2019-05-12"`. In this case i have getting `2` TAT. But expected is `1`

Comment: What is Turn around time? TAT?

Comment: TAT, on the other hand, means the Turn Around Time - this is the time within which the specified activity or step or process is agreed to be completed. TAT is a metric, which may form part of the SLAs agreed. TAT is usually associated with the 'timeliness' and 'completeness' measure.

Comment: Can you explain how you calculate TAT, other than code?

Comment: For Eg. I need to start work on "2019-05-01" and complete that work on "2019-05-05". TAT period is 5. But in between, I have holidays like "2019-05-03","2019-05-04", "2019-05-06","2019-05-10". In this case 2 days of holidays and one working day in between the Completed Date. So TAT period added 2 Days then my new completed date is "2019-05-07". But I have one more holiday that is "2019-05-06", So the result date is "2019-05-08". (Working Days are : "2019-05-01","2019-05-02","2019-05-05","2019-05-07","2019-05-08". 
 @LasseVågsætherKarlsen

Comment: So what you're saying is, start on the start day, then count 5 **working** days forward and find the end day? You want to make sure you have that many working days, and skip holidays?

Comment: So skip weekends, skip holidays?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just do what I said, do a loop, check if the date you're inspecting is a holiday (any type of day you don't want to count), then move forward without decreasing the counter. If you're on a working day, move forward *and* decrease the counter. When at 0, you're at the final date? (or some variation of thise)

Comment: Skip holidays only

Comment: If `TatPeriod` is 1, do you mean "return start date"?

Comment: Something like this? https://gist.github.com/lassevk/bbee7a626b3126ebb8e59a21ebdcb15b

Comment: Sorry, on that case TatPeriod means holiDayCount.

Comment: Isn't that just `endDate - startDate - tatPeriod`?

Comment: The reason I have all these questions is that your question is **really** unclear, you have a method that returns a date, but you want the number of holidays. In the future, take more care to write a clear and concise question.

Comment: And let me guess, if you have continuous holidays (as you've signaled as a "case"), it should count as 1, even if it ends up pushing the due date several days?

Comment: Sorry. In the future, I'll correct my mistakes while asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen's answer working fine for me.**

Link: **gist.github.com/lassevk/bbee7a626b3126ebb8e59a21ebdcb15b**

Code:

```
public static DateTime TatDueDateCalculator(DateTime assigningDate, int tatCount, IEnumerable<DateTime> holidays)
    {
        HashSet <DateTime> holidayLookup = new HashSet<DateTime>(holidays.Select(dt => dt.Date));

        DateTime dueDate = assigningDate.Date;
        while (tatCount > 1)
        {
            dueDate = dueDate.AddDays(1);
            while (holidayLookup.Contains(dueDate))
                dueDate = dueDate.AddDays(1);
            tatCount--;
        }
        return dueDate;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code yields the expected result (according to you example in the comments). It also accounts for holidays which are initially after the first due date.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var holidays = new List<DateTime>()
    {
        new DateTime(2019,05,03),
        new DateTime(2019,05,04),
        new DateTime(2019,05,06),
        new DateTime(2019,05,10),
    };
    int tatPeriod = 5;
    var assignDate = new DateTime(2019, 05, 01);
    var dueDate = Enumerable.Range(0, tatPeriod + holidays.Count)
                            .Select(offset => assignDate.AddDays(offset))
                            .Except(holidays)
                            .ElementAt(tatPeriod - 1);

    Console.WriteLine(dueDate);
    Console.Read();
}
```